# Get Player to half of a heart via vanilla potions

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I'm creating a bed trap that will lower a player to half a heart via potions that one can get in survival or any other tactic to lower health

Comment: Not sure why the close-votes. The question is absolutely clear to me.

Answer (score 4):

Use Poison. It will lower a player's health to half a heart but not kill them.

The higher the level, the faster it drains, but it won't kill them.

```
effect give @p poison 10 1 true
```

Answer (score 2):

If we were to consider vanilla, then you must get splash potions of Poison II.

The easiest way of doing so is farming spiders, creepers, nether wart, and find glowstone.

Follow [these instructions](https://www.digminecraft.com/brewing_recipes/make_potion_poison.php) to make a Potion of Poison, then use a glowstone dust to add up the Poison level (Now it's Poison II.) and add a gunpowder to make it a Splash Potion.

You said you want to use a bed trap, right? Place an observer somewhere unnoticeable, and same thing goes for the dispenser. Connect some redstone and add in the splash potions in.

---

An example by [**SF.**](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/9440/sf) (the simplest form):

[image: Basic Bed Trap Construction]

Now you got them hurt in their sleep.

Comment: [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YUZ3r.png) is probably the easiest setup providing the functionality. It will still leave the player with 1 heart if saturation was maxed out (golden carrot eaten recently). Steak - still 0.5 heart.